# Redondear decimales

Tags: php

buenos días.
Estoy intentando redondear los decimales de este número 139.73491 y que queden como 139.74.
Ya intente varias cosas pero no me queda.
Les comparto lo que e echo y no me ha quedado esperando que me puedan apoyar.

> Fallido 1

```
$numero = 139.73491;

echo round($numero, 2);
```

**resultado 139.73**

> Fallido 2

```
$numero = 139.73491;

echo round($numero * 100) / 100;
```

**Resultado 139.73**

> Fallido 3

```
$numero = 139.73491;

echo round($numero, 2, PHP_ROUND_HALF_UP);
```

**Resultado 139.73**

Espero que me puedan apoyar.

Saludos!

Comment: ¿Qué resultado esperarías de 139.73444?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que buscas es la funcion `ceil()` que se usa asi:

```
$numero = 139.73491;

echo ceil($numero * 100) / 100;
```

Comment: Muchas gracias. Agradecido!!

Comment: @Javierfr Con la cantidad de puntos que tienes aún no sabes que los agradecimientos estan muy bien, pero que para ayudar a los demás debes marcar como aceptada la respuesta que más te ha valido?  Sino la pregunta queda pendiente eternamente y el sistema la va relanzando de tanto en tanto buscando nuevas respuestas, pero si ya tienes una válida no tiene sentido dejarla así.